# C# for loop issue, returning

Tags: c#, for-loop

i have a code that i want to run 100 times. what i did is a for loop, but i get an exception ( must enter NOT duplicate values in a field in MySQL ) for duplicates, so i guess i did something wrong. I think that the for does not move forward. What am i doing wrong?

```
//loop for each user
for (int loop_counter = 1; loop_counter <= 100; loop_counter++)
{
    if (loop_counter < 10)
    {
        userid_value = company_value + "00" + loop_counter;
        username_value = company_value +"00" + loop_counter;
    }
    else
    {
        userid_value = company_value + "0" + loop_counter;
        username_value = company_value + "0" + loop_counter;
    }
    if (loop_counter == 100)
    {
        // Final Value of Label when all added
        Result_Label_Reply.Content = "100 Users added to" + company_value + ". Success.";
    }
    //radioButton Check to proceed
    if (Validation_Yes.IsChecked.Value && loop_counter < 100)
    {
        int companyId = dbm.FindCompanyId(company_value);
        if (dbm.AddUser(userid_value, username_value, pass, companyId))
        {
            Result_Label_Reply.Content = "User " + username_value + "added to" + company_value + " Successfully.";
            Validation_Yes.IsChecked = false;
            Company_Value_TextBox.Text = "";

        }
        else
        {
            Result_Label_Reply.Content = "Mysql exception ERROR.";
            Validation_Yes.IsChecked = false;
        }

    }

    else
    {
        Result_Label_Reply.Content = "Something went wrong, please try again.";

    }
}
```

Edit : here is the exception that i receive, which means that the function tries twice to enter the value of the first username. I have a company named Star so it tries to put Star001 but pointless since it says it has a dublicate entry

Note: It adds only the first user.

```
Activated   Event   Time    Duration    Thread
Exception: Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll ("Duplicate entry 'Star001' for key 'name'"). Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll ("Duplicate entry 'Star001' for key 'name'")   22.34s      [12128] <No Name>
```

Edit 2 : i give the code for the AddUser, though i believe the issue is not there, since the first user successfully is being added in the database.

```
public bool AddUser(string userid, string username, string password, int companyId)
{
    return ExecQuery("insert into users (id, name, pass, companyid) values (@id, @name, @pass, @cid)", 
    cmd =>
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", companyId);
            return cmd;
        });
}
```

Comment: Also include dbm.AddUser methods and the structure of the targeted user table.

Comment: What happened to the output?, which error message shows in the above ?

Comment: The problem is the following: loop_counter does not go ++ but remains the same.

Comment: @StarlexM.A no it is working perfectly. The issue seems to occur in different place.. What is the error message ? How many users added into it?

Comment: MySQL Exception uploaded, please check the edited preview.

Comment: Did you clear the database after every debugging process? If not, there you have your problem. If it already exists because it was added in your previous debugging attempt, it can't be added again. 
Another side fact: You are only adding 99 instead of 100 users, as your loop is running from 1 to 100, but your AddUser statement has the condition for your loop counter being lower than 100, so you are only adding 1 to 99.

Comment: Yes, i clear the database after every debuging attempt and each time the first user is added. For example Star001 is added but Star002 never added.

Comment: Then please show us what the AddUser method is doing as the provided code seems to be fine at first and second glance. Additionally: What's the value of "pass" you're passing to the AddUser method?

Comment: You expect `dbm.AddUser` returns `false` in case of an error, so catch exception inside `dbm.AddUser`.

Comment: I Added AddUser, though the issue is not there since the first value is successfully updated. But for some reason this code does not go to the 2nd value( doesn't take the loop_counter = 2 value )

Comment: So you assume it's the counter. If you place a breakpoint on the first line of your loop, the first iteration is loop_counter = 1 and it executes succesfully. In the second iteration, when it hits the breakpoint the second time, the value of loop_counter is really still 1? Please double check that, because then something is pretty broken and your counter has to be modified somewhere else.

Comment: is your database empty?

Comment: I just tried your loop with a `Console.WriteLine(username_value)` instead of `AddUser` and it looks fine. i.e. usernames are different. So the problem is somewhere in the second part inside `//radioButton Check to proceed`

Comment: Are you **110%** sure your first loop (when `loop_counter` is `1`) is executed without errors? Is user `Star001` really created during that loop or is it just a left over from a previous run?

Comment: One thing that catches my eye is that you set `Validation_Yes.IsChecked = false;` if `AddUser` returns true. So the loop only adds a single user (no duplicate tough)?

Comment: A user IS created, because each time i have to delete this 1 user , so i can test again to find out what is wrong. Now, for some reason the Result_Label_Reply rings " something went wrong " even though the user has been added. this is really strange. But i tested alone the functions that have something to do with the database and each one alone works perfect.

Comment: Problem solved, @GeorgPatscheider you were right, the validation had the issue, found it out on debugging